# Synchronous XMLHttpReqests in JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, standards, synchronous

I am using the following JavaScript function object to handle requests to the server:

```
function Request(query, url) {
    var that = this;
    this.request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    this.response = ''; 

    this.set_response = function() {
        if (that.request.readyState==4 && that.request.status==200) {
            that.response = that.request.response;    
        }   
    }   

    this.request.onreadystatechange = this.set_response;
    this.request.open('POST', url, false); 
    this.request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    this.request.send(query);
}
```

With this object I can do something like:

```
var needed_data = new Request('data=needed', 'serverside.php').response;
```

Now the data I needed from the server is stored nicely in the `needed_data` variable (as a json encoded string).The problem is using a synchronous request in the main thread has been deprecated. I was hoping someone could help me figure out a way to achieve the same result whilst being standards compliant.

Comment: No. Making your code asynchronous will require a restructuring of all the code that uses the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to make it asynchronous.

```
//allow to pass a callback
function Request(query, url, callback) {
    var that = this;
    this.request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    this.response = ''; 

    this.set_response = function() {
        if (that.request.readyState==4 && that.request.status==200) {
            that.response = that.request.response;
            callback && callback(that); //invoke the callback when data is available
        }   
    }   

    this.request.onreadystatechange = this.set_response;
    this.request.open('POST', url, true); //make the call async
    this.request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    this.request.send(query);
}

new Request('data=needed', 'serverside.php', function (request) {
    console.log(request.response);
});
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. Now I need to go back and edit a bunch of code. Another question, here: `callback && callback(that);` is this checking first to make sure there is a parameter called callback set before invoking the callback function (not invoking otherwise)?

Comment: @not__p that is correct. It's the same as doing `if (callback) callback(that)`

Answer (score 0):

You should **never** be using a synchronous `XMLHttpRequest` in the same thread as the rest of your application.

```
function request(query, url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();   
  xhr.open('POST', url, true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200 && callback) {
      callback(xhr.responseText);
    } 
  };
  xhr.send(query);
  return xhr;
}

request('data=needed', 'serverside.php', function(responseText){
  var needed_data = JSON.parse(responseText);
});
```

Comment: I don't know about __never__, apparently using synchronous requests is acceptable in a Web Worker.

Comment: @not__p you are correct, I've edited my answer to reflect that.